# Where do i get and how to install _namemapper.pyd for Python 2.7 on Windows

Tags: python

I have Python 2.7 installed on my windows system with Cheetah. Below is the error i am getting, when i try to use the cheetah.template object with the .tmpl file.

```
from Cheetah.Template import Template
t = Template(file='home.tmpl')
C:\wamp\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cheetah\Compiler.py:1509: UserWarning:
You don't have the C version of NameMapper installed! I'm disabling Cheetah's us
eStackFrames option as it is painfully slow with the Python version of NameMappe
r. You should get a copy of Cheetah with the compiled C version of NameMapper.
  "\nYou don't have the C version of NameMapper installed! "

from Cheetah.Template import Template
t = Template(file='home.tmpl')
print t

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\wamp\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cheetah\Template.py", line 1005,
in __str__
    rc = getattr(self, mainMethName)()
  File "_wamp_www_b121pyraw_b121pycheetah_home_tmpl.py", line 89, in respond
  File "C:\wamp\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cheetah\NameMapper.py", line 246,
 in valueFromSearchList
    _raiseNotFoundException(key, searchList)
  File "C:\wamp\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cheetah\NameMapper.py", line 167,
 in _raiseNotFoundException
    raise NotFound(excString)
Cheetah.NameMapper.NotFound: cannot find 'firstdivcontents'
```

I searched for _namemapper.pyd for python 2.7, but i am not getting. I found the file for upto 2.6 only.
Do i have to downgrade to python 2.6, or is there any other method to install it.

And also how to install _namemapper.pyd  to work with python, if at all i find it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pyd files are created by compiling the C files which comes with the Package. This is done on installing, if you have a C compiler handy. If not, you in this case get a Python fall back. Some packages will just refuse to install.

The solution for Windows people without a C compiler is to install pre-compiled C binary packages. Cheetah seems to not have any: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Cheetah/2.4.4

So you would need to install a C-compiler. MinGW is a good option, I hear.

**However, I don't think that is your problem at all. Your actual error seems to have nothing to do with this warning.**

So if you include your failing code, people more used to Cheetah than me can probably tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

File `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Cheetah\Compiler.py`

Comment the following lines starting with line# 1506 to get rid of the error.

```
#        if not NameMapper.C_VERSION:
#            if not sys.platform.startswith('java'):
#                warnings.warn(
#                    "\nYou don't have the C version of NameMapper installed! "
#                    "I'm disabling Cheetah's useStackFrames option as it is "
#                    "painfully slow with the Python version of NameMapper. "
#                    "You should get a copy of Cheetah with the compiled C version of NameMapper."
#                    )
```

Comment: It is only a warning, the non C version of namemapper will be used. Commenting out the warning is rather silly advice in my view - you could simply ignore the warning, you will just get worse performance using the python version of namemapper. So downvoting this answer.

Answer (score -1):

I made a copy of namemapper python file and I solved my problem just making a modify on the file extension from `_namemapper.pyd` to `_namemapper.so` and it worked just fine.

I cannot affirm this is a right practice but worked for me.